# Why we pass 50 limitations in these file in open layers / GeoServer?

Tags: gis, openlayers, openlayers-3, geoserver

Please let us know what is use of below code and why we are passing the **PARTIAL_BUFFER_STRATEGY_SIZE** as 50 by default ?

```
<context-param>
    <!-- see comments on the PARTIAL-BUFFER strategy -->
    <!-- this sets the size of the buffer.  default is "50" = 50kb -->

    <param-name>PARTIAL_BUFFER_STRATEGY_SIZE</param-name>
    <param-value>50</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

If we will change the **PARTIAL_BUFFER_STRATEGY_SIZE** value then what will effect on the application?

Answer (score 0):

If you look higher up in the web.xml the serviceStrategy comments explain what this is used for. https://github.com/gem/oq-ui-geoserver/blob/master/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml#L10

Comment: how and why we are doing these limitations?

Answer (score 0):

As the [GeoServer manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/config.html#set-a-service-strategy) explains there are several possible strategies:

> SPEED
>
> Serves output right away. This is the fastest strategy, but proper OGC
> errors are usually omitted.
>
> BUFFER
>
> Stores the whole result in memory, and then serves it after the output
> is complete. This ensures proper OGC error reporting, but delays the
> response quite a bit and can exhaust memory if the response is large.
>
> FILE
>
> Similar to BUFFER, but stores the whole result in a file instead of in
> memory. Slower than BUFFER, but ensures there won’t be memory issues.
>
> PARTIAL-BUFFER
>
> A balance between BUFFER and SPEED, this strategy tries to buffer in
> memory a few KB of response, then serves the full output.

Then as the comment you show says if you choose PARTIAL-BUFFER you can set what size that buffer is, in this case 50kB.

Comment: If we change 50 to 100 then what effect on my application.

Comment: it will use twice as much memory per image request than before

Comment: and what is the purpose of this 50 pass in here, Will it increase or decrease the execution time

Comment: it will be faster for some images, if you don't understand what it does leave it alone